# UIImpactFeedbackGenerator not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to use the new `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` for haptic feedback, but it isn't working.

- Testing on iPhone 7
- iOS 10.1.1
- System Haptic setting is enabled

I'm using the following code example in Objective-C

```
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator *myGen = [[UIImpactFeedbackGenerator alloc] init];
[myGen initWithStyle:(UIImpactFeedbackStyleMedium)];
[myGen impactOccurred];
myGen = NULL;
```

I'm triggering it inside a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` delegate.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: It is recommended to call `prepare` before calling `impactOccurred`, have you tried that?

Comment: @donnywals yeah, i tried that as well, didn't help :/

Comment: Have you tried not releasing `myGen` it in the same method ? Also, try moving the declaration of your generator somewhere earlier in the lifecycle and make sure you `prepare` it before firing. Does this help ?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, it turned out that while working with real time camera input, UIImpactFeedbackGenerator will not give any haptic feedback

Comment: sooo.. whats the approach here ? if we have a Camera App we cant use this ?

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem, from the documentation:

> ...Note that calling these methods does not play haptics directly.
>   Instead, it informs the system of the event. The system then
>   determines whether to play the haptics based on the device, the
>   application’s state, the amount of battery power remaining, and other
>   factors. For example, haptic feedback is currently played only:
>
> - On a device with a supported Taptic Engine (iPhone 7 and iPhone 7    Plus).
> - When the app is running in the foreground. When the System
> - Haptics setting is enabled.

I guess you just have to trust the system to known when it should fire...
I didn't like this approach for obvious reasons -so used [AudioServicesPlaySystemSound and k​System​Sound​ID_Vibrate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/1405248-audioservicesplaysystemsound?language=objc):

> ...On some iOS devices, you can pass the k​System​Sound​ID_Vibrate
>   constant to invoke vibration. On other iOS devices, calling this
>   function with that constant does nothing.

**Objective-C**

```
import AudioToolbox
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

**Swift 3**

```
import AudioToolbox
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably you should not use double init.

```
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator *myGen = [[UIImpactFeedbackGenerator alloc] initWithStyle: UIImpactFeedbackStyleMedium];
[myGen impactOccurred];
```

Also please make sure that you did `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setAllowHapticsAndSystemSoundsDuringRecording:YES];` before this call.

Answer (score 1):

I asked an Apple Engineer at WWDC 2017 why my haptic request would sometimes fail, and he had me call `impactOccurred` on the next run loop like this:

```
[self.feedbackGenerator performSelector:@selector(impactOccurred) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: Still not working for me. I noticed that if I print the feeback object, it says it is not prepared, even when I do call prepare as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case - the setting in iphone was disabled.

> Settings -> Sounds and Haptics -> System Haptics

After enabling it - haptics become work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### How to use Haptic Feedback for a better experience in iOS

###### UIImpactFeedbackGenerator

```
private let feedbackGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)

//The Impact Feedback style has three variations 
// .light  .medium  .heavy


feedbackGenerator.impactOccurred()
```